# Dynamically create highcharts with bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, carousel

I want to load different highcharts in a carousel from bootstrap. I load the data from php and then I use it in javascript.

But what's the best way to load de highcharts? How can I do this is in javascript? Should I create a new highchart every time you click on left or right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is, create your charts in separate div elements which is hidden in page load, then slide them using carousel.

Comment: Won't that take a load of time when I want to load 10 highcharts in one time?

Comment: Just load this using php / javascript and call your carousel after document ready.

Comment: Loading the charts on each slide / slide navigation click will slow down your app.